# What does auto&& do?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

This is the code from C++11 Notes Sample by Scott Meyers,

```
int x;
auto&& a1 = x;             // x is lvalue, so type of a1 is int&
auto&& a2 = std::move(x);  // std::move(x) is rvalue, so type of a2 is int&&
```

I am having trouble understanding `auto&&`.
I have some understanding of `auto`, from which I would say that `auto& a1 = x` should make type of `a1` as `int&`

Which from Quoted code, seems wrong.

I wrote this small code, and ran under gcc.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    auto& a1 = x;           //line 8
    cout << a1 << endl;
    ++a1;
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Output = `4 (newline) 5`
Then I modified line 8 as `auto&& a1 = x;`, and ran. Same output.

My question : Is `auto&` equal to `auto&&`?
If they are different what does `auto&&` do?

Comment: I think `auto&` and `auto&&` are equivalent if rhs is a lvalue. `auto&` will give you an error if rhs is an rvalue.

Comment: [Lvalue references and rvalue references are similar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx)

Comment: An `auto&&` variable means the same as a `T&&` parameter in a function template.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The code is right. `auto&& p = expr` means the type of `p` is `T&&` where `T` will be inferred from `expr`. The `&&` here indicates a rvalue reference, so e.g.

```
auto&& p = 1;
```

will infer `T == int` and thus the type of `p` is `int&&`.

However, references can be collapsed according to the rule:

```
T& &   == T&
T& &&  == T&
T&& &  == T&
T&& && == T&&
```

(This feature is used to implement perfect forwarding in C++11.)

In the case

```
auto&& p = x;
```

as `x` is an lvalue, an rvalue reference cannot be bound to it, but if we infer `T = int&` then the type of `p` will become `int& && = int&`, which is an lvalue reference, which can be bound to `x`. Only in this case `auto&&` and `auto&` give the same result. These two are different though, e.g.

```
auto& p = std::move(x);
```

is incorrect because `std::move(x)` is an rvalue, and the lvalue reference cannot be bound to it.

Please read [C++ Rvalue References Explained](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)  for a walk through.

Comment: CppNext has listed same rule : http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/12/onward-forward/

Comment: Thanks! for the explanation. Also the link about Rvalue is helpful.